# Quick sort implementation in C

Tags: c, quicksort, qsort

To answer everyone's first question: Yes, this is for school.
That being said, I feel like I'm pretty close to getting this to work, at least partially.  Seems to sort most of the data, but I can't see any pattern to what is not being sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quicksort(int *values, int size);
void printout(int[], int size);

void main(){
    printf("starting");
    int size=20;
    int values[size];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        values[i]=(rand()%113);
    }
    printf("\nBefore Sort:\n");
    printout(values,size);
    quicksort(values, size);
    printf("\nAfter Sort:\n");
    printout(values,size);
}

void printout(int values[],int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (i % 20 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%3i ", values[i]);
    }
}

void quicksort(int *values, int size){
    if (size < 2){
        return;
    }
    int pivot=values[size];
    int left[size];
    int right[size];
    int center[size];
    int i,lc,rc,cc;  //counters for left, right and center arrays
    lc=rc=cc=0; //initially 0
    
    for (i=0; i<size-1; i++){
        if (values[i] < pivot){
            left[lc]=values[i];
            lc++;
        }
        else if (values[i] > pivot){
            right[rc]=values[i];
            rc++;
        }
        else{
            center[cc]=values[i];
            cc++;
        }
    }
    quicksort(left, lc);
    quicksort(right, rc);
    int lc2,rc2,cc2;
    lc2=rc2=cc2=0;  //note the first variable is lowercase L, not 1
    while (lc2+cc2+rc2 < size-1){  // here we recombine our arrays
        while (lc2 < lc){
            values[lc2+rc2+cc2] = left[lc2];
            lc2+=1;
        }
        while (cc2 < cc){
            values[lc2+rc2+cc2] = center[cc2];
            cc2+=1;
        }
        while (rc2 < rc){
            values[lc2+rc2+cc2] = right[rc2];
            rc2+=1;
        }
    }
    
}
```

My output for this is as follows:

**Before Sort:**

`41  48  6  58  72  17  65  91  68  56  55  8  3  103  17  39  57  77  81  12`

**After Sort:**

`6  8  17  41  48  58  72  65  68  56  55  3  17  39  91  57  77  103 81  12`

It's definitely doing something... Anybody have any ideas as to what the heck I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included tips on debugging that you can apply in the future to find problems like these.

#### Problem 1

```
int pivot=values[size];
```

size is past the end of the range being sorted. At the top level when the range is the entire array that means it's outside the array. And at the other levels it's either outside the array or the pivot value is from a different range.

Discovering this defect may require either careful code review or a tool designed to catch this sort of error such as is built into some compilers.

A more difficult method involves inspecting the runtime behavior, either with print statements or a debugger, and recognizing that the first pivot is not a value in the array. Testing with known input instead of random input helps with this method because it makes it more likely that you'll notice anything unexpected.

---

#### Problem 2

You also do not move the pivot into the correct location.

One technique for discovering this would be to check post-conditions. For example at the end of `quicksort()` the range should be sorted. So if you insert `printout(values,size);` at the end of that function then might notice in a few short cases where just the last element is out of order. Additional print statements can help you trace what's causing this.

---

#### Problem 3

`main()` must return `int`, not `void`.

Using a stricter compiler will catch this for you.

Comment: Thanks for that seemingly obvious suggestion regarding the pivot.
I come from the land of python with it's wonderful index checking and must have missed that.  Still having some issues but a definite step in the right direction.

What exactly do you mean when you say I'm not moving the pivot correctly?  As far as I can tell when I step through the array anything equal to the pivot (including the original pivot itself) will be copied into "center".

Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @facepalmer Print out the contents of left, center, and right after you fill them up. Or just look at them using a debugger.

Comment: There were a few funny things going on, most of them to do with indices:
First, the pivot was wrong.
Secondly, I was only actually adding size-1 items to left/right/center, so I was always missing one in my initial sort.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're choosing the pivot wrong - `values[size]` lies outside of the range. If you want to use the last element, use `values[size - 1]`.